How can I import the private keys of a MultiBit Classic wallet into Electrum?
I had an old Multibit Classic program on my computer. I was able to open the private key using OpenSSL. I downloaded Electrum to my computer and created a new wallet importing the private key. However, now when I open Electrum I don't see my bitcoins, the balance and history show empty. Is there anything I can do?

Hi Nakke, there are 278 questions on this site with the "multibit" tag, including 16 also tagged with "electrum". Are you sure none of them have a solution to your problem?

Hi. I have tried searching but have not found an answer. Many of the questions are related to decryption and I do not have this problem.

Is it possible that your Electrum wallet only created addresses of a different output type than the one you were using with MultiBit? Have you checked whether Electrum and MultiBit use the same derivation paths?
